# Rest-Assured Java Post Request

Tags: java, rest, testing, rest-assured

Is there a way to make the test post request and after that the change to be reverted because it actually makes a real post to the server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports transactions then you can run the test inside a transcation (see for example see [spring testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-tx)) or you could clear your database after (or before) each test (if you don't run parallel tests).

Comment: i dont have a database except the one that is in tomcat 7 (apache derby ) only local runtime db